# DVD/CD drive not showing

Tags: dvd

I am very very new to Ubuntu - running 14.04 on an Acer Aspire - I need to copy something to a dvd but I can't locate the drive at all.

I need clear instructions on how to do this please, I know nothing at all about this kind of thing.

I have looked at other Q&A's but could not find exactly what I need.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting a blank DVD in to the drive? If so, what happened?

Comment: You can also press superkey and then type disks to run the utility which shows what devices you have on your system.

Answer (score 0):

Install Brasero using Ubuntu Software Center, restart into Ubuntu then  insert the disc once your desktop is loaded.